# How do I write raw text to dom4j.Branch?

Tags: java, dom4j

I have a case where I need to write a string directly as is as the text of a node using dom4j. Yes I know this is bad practice but we're sort-of stuck for this one use.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Exactly what do you mean with "directly as is"? Do you want it to be "unescaped" according to XML rules?

Comment: Yes, unescaped where we better have it correct.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
XMLWriter writer = new XMLWriter();
writer.setEscape(false);
```